# Facebook Marketing API Not working when using Exactly what they are asking for?

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My code Thats producing the error, I have * out all of the details for obvious resins ,but i can assure you that the details are correct as of my knowledge

```
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebook_business.adobjects.campaign import Campaign
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi

access_token = '#############'
app_secret = '##############'
app_id = '###############'
id = '############'
FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token)

fields = [
]
params = {
  'name': 'My campaign',
  'objective': 'OUTCOME_TRAFFIC',
  'status': 'PAUSED',
  'special_ad_categories': [],
}
print (AdAccount(id).create_campaign(
  fields=fields,
  params=params,
))
```

So this is the sample code for the marketing api documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis/get-started
Ive put in my own details:
Access token
app secret
app id
heres the issue, i put in my ad account id and i get an error ill show it below, if i put the sandbox ad account id i get the same error. I have checked the graph api documentation as it asks me to but to no avail im not the greatest at understanding documentation  but i try i havent found anything in the graph api documentation to assist me

```
exception has occurred: FacebookRequestError


  Message: Call was not successful
  Method:  POST
  Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/1319248112287380/campaigns
  Params:  {'name': 'My campaign', 'objective': 'OUTCOME_TRAFFIC', 'status': 'PAUSED', 'special_ad_categories': '[]'}

  Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID '1319248112287380' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "fbtrace_id": "AEe1jri5iGEm023TkvE98-x"
      }
    }
  File "C:\Users\danie\Documents\easyapps\facebook_mvp.py", line 25, in <module>
    print (AdAccount(id).create_campaign(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
facebook_business.exceptions.FacebookRequestError: 

  Message: Call was not successful
  Method:  POST
  Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/1319248112287380/campaigns
  Params:  {'name': 'My campaign', 'objective': 'OUTCOME_TRAFFIC', 'status': 'PAUSED', 'special_ad_categories': '[]'}

  Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID '1319248112287380' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "fbtrace_id": "AEe1jri5iGEm023TkvE98-x"
      }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated

I want the code to Send a request to the api, from there i will be expanding it, ive tried to swap all the ids out ive tried creating a new account but no luck, from there i will be turning it all to a library etc anyway,

Comment: The error message is quite clear: *Unsupported post request. Object with ID '1319248112287380' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api*

Comment: I have changed the ad account id multiple times, which that is, ive tried sandbox mode ad id aswell ive even created a new account but to no avail. that error is saying the ad account id doesnt exist but it does ive verified it multiple times

Comment: You are familiar with how a coma, and the conjunction "or" work in the English language, yes? _"that error is saying the ad account id doesnt exist"_ - no, it is _not_ saying _just_ that. So I am guessing, it might simply be the _"cannot be loaded due to missing permissions"_ part that applies here. And which permissions your used access token actually encompasses, we don't currently know.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample, it looks like you are trying to create campaigns under a specific ad account. The error message is indicating that either you have the wrong ad account ID, or you do not have the correct permissions.

When you generate the access token, I believe you will need `ads_management` permissions for what you are trying to achieve.

My advice is to use the [graph API explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to grant the proper permissions and to test the call.

You can verify which permissions your access token has by using the [access token debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/). Make sure it has atleast `ads_read` and `ads_management` in the `scopes` field.

Another tip, you can grab the ad account ID from the url when you load ads manager. It is the `act` GET param.

Comment: Wierd, i have both those permissions, and the api tool using my token is working?, but as soon as i do it programatically it doesnt work, must be an error with the code

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error for 3 days. Turns out the account ID needs to start with act_ before the actual account ID number. That's what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

So after much investigation i figured it out,
The facebook Ads API is outdated with python atleast using python2, I tried Using curl as a subprocess with python and Success works flawlessly
heres the code

```
import subprocess

# Define the curl command as a list of strings
curl_command = [
    'curl',
    '-X',
    'POST',
    '-F',
    'name="My campaign"',
    '-F',
    'objective="OUTCOME_TRAFFIC"',
    '-F',
    'status="PAUSED"',
    '-F',
    'special_ad_categories=[]',
    '-F',
    f'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>',
    f'https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/campaigns'
]

# Execute the curl command
try:
    result = subprocess.run(curl_command, capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
    print(result.stdout)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(f"Command failed with error: {e}")
```

Comment: Oh interesting. Yes, I assumed python3. The package does seem to work for me in python3.